Why does my querySelector not select the correct ID for a step in an HTML form?
My digiNextStepMobil does not get called properly and the form does not go the step2, when I press the button.
HTML
<form id="digi-productGuideForm-mobil">
  <div id="digi-step1-1" class="digi-step">
    <h2>Hvor skal ladestanderen placeres?</h2>
    <label>
      <input id="beskrivelser" type="radio" name="placement" value="commonParking">
      Fælles p-plads
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="placement" value="parkingGarage">
      P-kælder
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="placement" value="residentParking"> 
        Beboerens egen p-plads
    </label><br>
    <nav id="digi-buttons">
      <button type="button" id="digi-næsteKnap1" onclick="digiNextStepMobil()">
        Næste
      </button>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="digi-step2-1" class="digi-step" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Hvor mange ladeudtag har foreningen brug for?</h2>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="outlets" value="upTo10"> 
      Op til 10 ladeudtag
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="outlets" value="moreThan10"> 
      Mere end 10 ladeudtag
    </label><br>
    <nav id="digi-buttons">
      <button type="button" id="digi-tilbageKnap1" onclick="digiPreviousStepMobil()">
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> 
          arrow_back_ios 
        </span> 
        Tilbage
      </button>
      <button type="button" id="digi-næsteKnap1" onclick="digiNextStepMobil()">
        Næste
      </button>
    </nav>
  </div>
  
  <!--
     And so on with step digi-step3-1 and digi-step 4-1.
  -->

SCRIPT
function digiNextStepMobil() {
  var digiCurrentStep = document.querySelector('.digi-step:not([style*="display: none"])');
  var digiNextStep    = digiCurrentStep.nextElementSibling;

  if (digiCurrentStep.id === "digi-step1-1") {
    var digiPlacement = document.querySelector('input[name="placement"]:checked').value;
    
    if (digiPlacement === "residentParking" || digiPlacement === "parkingGarage") {
      document.getElementById("digi-step2-1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("digi-step3-1").style.display = "none";
      digiNextStep = document.getElementById("digi-step4-1");
    }
  }

  if (digiCurrentStep.id === "digi-step3.1") {
    var digiHomes = document.querySelector('input[name="homes"]:checked').value;
    
    if (digiHomes === "moreThan40") {
      digiShowResultMobil();
      return;
    }
  }

  if (digiNextStep) {
    digiShowStep(digiNextStep);
  }
}

I tried giving the ID's differnet names in terms of perhaps dots and (-) not being allowed, but this was not the case.

You query document.getElementById("digi-step3-1") but there is no digi-step3-1 in your code.

Your HTML is invalid as posted <nav id="digi-buttons"> id must be unique so we can close this as a typo. ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

id="digi-tilbageKnap1" you posted this twice.  Ids must be unique in this error html.  It might work if you declare the ids multiple times in proper css, but it doesn't work in javascript.  So always give different id.

my advice, with a little more knowledge of HTML5 and CSS3,
you will get lighter and easier to maintain code ;)


const digiForm = document.querySelector('#digi-productGuideForm-mobil');

digiForm.next_Field.addEventListener('click', ()=>f_showField(+1));
digiForm.prev_Field.addEventListener('click', ()=>f_showField(-1));

function f_showField( mov )
  {
  digiForm.className = `digi-step${ +digiForm.className.match(/(\d+)/)[0] + mov }`;
  }
form     { width   : 30em;   }
fieldset { margin  : 1em;    }
label    { display : block;  }
legend   { padding : 0 .5em; }

nav > button { width : 6em }

form.digi-step1 fieldset:not(:nth-child(1)) ,
form.digi-step2 fieldset:not(:nth-child(2)) ,
form.digi-step3 fieldset:not(:nth-child(3)) ,
form.digi-step4 fieldset:not(:nth-child(4)) {  display: none; }  

form.digi-step1 nav > button[name="prev_Field"] ,
form.digi-step4 nav > button[name="next_Field"] { visibility:hidden; }
<form id="digi-productGuideForm-mobil" class="digi-step1">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Hvor skal ladestanderen placeres?</legend>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="placement" value="commonParking"   > Fælles p-plad          </label> 
    <label> <input type="radio" name="placement" value="parkingGarage"   > P-kælder               </label> 
    <label> <input type="radio" name="placement" value="residentParking" > Beboerens egen p-plads </label> 
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Hvor mange ladeudtag har foreningen brug for?</legend>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="outlets" value="upTo10"     > Op til 10 ladeudtag   </label> 
    <label> <input type="radio" name="outlets" value="moreThan10" > Mere end 10 ladeudtag </label> 
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend> fieldset 3</legend>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="ccc" value="x31" > ccc+1 </label> 
    <label> <input type="radio" name="ccc" value="x32" > ccc+2 </label> 
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend> fieldset 4</legend>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="ddd" value="x41" > ddd+1 </label> 
    <label> <input type="radio" name="ddd" value="x42" > ddd+2 </label> 
  </fieldset>

  <nav>
    <button type="button" name="prev_Field"> Tilbage </button>
    <button type="button" name="next_Field"> Næste   </button>
  </nav>

  <!-- ... -->
</form>




Here I use the data-* attribute and the dataset property to decide what fieldset is going to be visible.
I also added validation of the form fields within the fieldset to enable the "next" button. Fieldsets are useful for dividing up form fields.


document.forms['digi-productGuideForm-mobil'].addEventListener('input', e => {
  let fieldset = e.target.closest('fieldset');
  let form = e.target.form;
  // get the number of invalid form fields
  // and make invalid a boolean (!!)
  let invalid = !![...fieldset.elements].filter(elm => !elm.validity.valid).length;
  // set disabled equal the invalid valiable
  fieldset.elements.next.disabled = invalid;
  // enable submit button when all are valid
  let forminvalid = form.checkValidity();
  form.submitbutton.disabled = !forminvalid;
});

document.forms['digi-productGuideForm-mobil'].addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(e.target);
  console.log([...data]);
});

document.forms['digi-productGuideForm-mobil'].addEventListener('click', e => {
  let fieldset = e.target.closest('fieldset');
  let form = e.target.form;
  // set form[data-fieldset] based on the button clicked
  switch (e.target.name) {
    case 'next':
      form.dataset.fieldset = fieldset.dataset.next;
      break;
    case 'prev':
      form.dataset.fieldset = fieldset.dataset.prev;
      break;
  }
});
form fieldset {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form[data-fieldset="digi-step1-1"] fieldset[name="digi-step1-1"] {
  display: flex;
}

form[data-fieldset="digi-step2-1"] fieldset[name="digi-step2-1"] {
  display: flex;
}

form[data-fieldset="digi-step3-1"] fieldset[name="digi-step3-1"] {
  display: flex;
}

button {
  background-color: PaleGreen;
  color: black;
  border-radius: .3em;
  transition: all 1s;
}

button:disabled {
  background-color: DarkSalmon;
  opacity: .5;
}
<form name="digi-productGuideForm-mobil" data-fieldset="digi-step1-1">
  <fieldset name="digi-step1-1" data-next="digi-step2-1">
    <h2>Hvor skal ladestanderen placeres?</h2>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="placement" value="commonParking">
      Fælles p-plads
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="placement" value="parkingGarage">
      P-kælder
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="placement" value="residentParking"> 
      Beboerens egen p-plads
    </label>
    <label>
      <button name="next" type="button" disabled>Next</button>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="digi-step2-1" data-next="digi-step3-1" data-prev="digi-step1-1">
    <h2>Hvor mange ladeudtag har foreningen brug for?</h2>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="outlets" value="upTo10"> 
      Op til 10 ladeudtag
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="outlets" value="moreThan10"> 
      Mere end 10 ladeudtag
    </label>
    <label>
      <button name="prev" type="button">prev</button>
      <button name="next" type="button" disabled>Next</button>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="digi-step3-1" data-prev="digi-step2-1">
    <p>Submit</p>
    <label>
      <button name="prev" type="button">prev</button>
      <button type="submit" name="submitbutton" disabled>Submit</button>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>



